# Recrusive on integer

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have a set of integers as follow:

`1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 ...`

And I would like to have a close recursive form of the sort `3*(n+1)-1` where, for a given `n` I can be able to compute the related integer of the sequence.

Unfortunately, the sequence is somehow not uniform, since the difference between consecutive integer is not every time the same:

`1,2,1,2,1,1,1,...,1`

The problem as one can see, is the two `2` at the second and fourth position of the series given by the `4-2` and `7-5` all the other integers up to infinity as a consecutive difference of `1` (i.e.: `13-12`) . 
So my question is, do exist a close form to express this recurrence of number?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I am absolutely certain you can do some trickery with floor functions, but I'm not very good at that myself. At least not at getting something nice-looking.

Comment: Anyway, this is $n+2$ for $n \ge 5$.

Comment: @Crostul yes but what about for `n<5` ? :) this is the tricky point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the floor function $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ your sequence can be described by the formula
$$n+2-\lfloor \frac{4}{n} \rfloor +2 \cdot\lfloor \frac{1}{n} \rfloor$$

Comment: it was what I was searching. I didn't tough about the `floor` function. Many thanks.